# Rails view: shuffle table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble figuring out how to shuffle table values in a view. I have a table in my view with a left and a right column, and would like to shuffle only the right column.

show.html.erb

```
<table>
  <% @items.each do |item| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.left %><td>
    <td><%= item.right %><td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The "left" and "right" share the same primary id in the database. Any suggestions about how to shuffle only one side?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shuffle`, do this way

```
<% shuffled_items = @items.shuffle %>
<% @items.each_with_index do |item, index| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.left %><td>
    <td><%= shuffled_items[index].right %><td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For details read this documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle

Comment: Ohh! Didn't even know that something like this exists.Very nice :)

Comment: that does not produce the requested output. You end up with one row with 2*n tds...

Comment: I have updated my answer, please make the correction

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to have 2 arrays.

`@items_left` and `@items_right`

eg:

```
items = Item.a_scope
@items_left = items
@items_right = items.pluck(:right).shuffle #if you are on > rails 3.2

# @items_left = items.pluck(:left) #if only that attribute is needed
```

so you can use it as follows

```
<table>
  <% @items_left.each_with_index do |item, i| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.left %><td>
      <td><%= @items_right[i] %><td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```